# Multiple conditions in an IF statement in Excel VBA "end if without block if""

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors, conditional-statements

im total beginner in VBA, i'm working on cleaning web logs from unnecessary data (rows containing .jpg, .gif, ...) I've found code which does exactly what i need to do, but i get ERROR "compile error: end if without block if"

```
Sub clean() 
Dim r As Long, endRow As Long, pasteRowIndex As Long

endRow = 321085 

For r = endRow To 1 Step -1  
  Select Case Cells(r, Columns("F").Column).Value
        Case "*.jpg*", "*.JPG*", "*.gif*"
            Rows(r).Delete
        Case Else
            ' Do nothing...

    End Select

    End If
 Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove `End If`.

Comment: remove the `End If`

Comment: Thank you, i tried it it does not give error anymore but still won't delete rows containing .jpg,.JPG,.gif.

Comment: Step through your code with `F8`, and make sure that Column F's cells do have that value.  Also, FYI, you can just do `Cells(r, "F")`

Comment: Select case does not allow the use of wildcard matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a wildcard with `Select Case`, you can use `Like`:

```
Sub clean() 
Dim r As Long, endRow As Long, pasteRowIndex As Long

' I assume your column F has the most data
endRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row 

For r = endRow To 1 Step -1  
  Select Case True
        Case Cells(r, "F").Value Like "*.jpg*" or Cells(r, "F").Value Like "*.JPG*" or Cells(r, "F").Value Like "*.gif*"
            Rows(r).Delete
        Case Else
            ' Do nothing...
    End Select
 Next r
End Sub
```

Edit: There's likely a better way, by putting the values you want to find in an Array, then search the array, but the above should work with the current method.